# Submanifold of Kähler manifold is projective

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Good time of day.

I have the following question.

$X$- is a compact Kähler manifold (it may be projective or not). And $Y\subset X$ a complex submanifold. Also there is a holomorphic two-form $\phi \in \Gamma(X,\Omega_{X}^{2})$ such that $\phi|_{Y}=0$. And I try to understand why $Y$ is projective.

My thoughts about this are the following: It is known that complex submanifolds of Kähler manifolds are Kähler manifolds. It follows that $Y$ is a Kähler manifold too. After this I'm trying to use Kodaira embedding theorem for proving that $Y$ is projective. I don't know how to prove that we have positive line bundle over $Y$.

Possibly there are other more convenient attempts to this problem. Please if you don't mind please explain it in more details. Thank you!

Comment: This is false. Let $X = Y$ be a non-projective Kähler manifold and $\phi = 0$.

Comment: The version where $\phi\neq 0$ is also false, taking $Y$ non-projective Kähler and $X = Y \times S$ where $S$ is a K3 surface, abelian surface, etc. and $\phi$ is pulled-back from $S$.

Comment: It is not a good idea to ask here for a solution of your exam problem!

Comment: @Spenser thank you for your answer. As I understand $\phi=0$ via pull-back? If X will be projective is it possible?

Comment: @Sasha I'm not studying at university and I study kahler geometry for myself. Advises and solutions of certain problem help me to understand subject.

Comment: @UserIn Yes, if $\phi=0$ then $\phi|_Y = 0$. If $X$ is projective, then so is any closed complex submanifold.

Comment: @UserIn: I just happen to know that this problem was given yesterday for a home examination, so this looks exactly as if you are trying to use people here to solve this problem for you.

Comment: @Sasha your comment is very strange because people in this forum use other people for solving their problems and for obtaining new knowledge. They explain to each other sophisticated material. Possibly my question seems very simple for experts in this field. How can I understand subject without tutors If I wouldn't ask questions? I was thinking about this question during two days and I was not able to find a solution. I decided to ask people who knows. Thank you

Comment: Are you asking about complex tori fibers of a fibration whose total space is a hyper-Kaehler manifold?